# Maximizing the total viewership of the posters using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, dynamic-programming

You  must  advertise  your  sorority’s  big  party  along  an M foot-long  corridor.   There  are  bulletin  boards  at  positions x1,x2, . . . ,xn along  this  corridor  (in  sorted order from north to south). If you place a poster at position xi in the corridor, then vi>0 people will see that poster. (Some locations are more popular than others.) However, to be fair to other groups on campus, any two posters that you place must be separated by at least D feet. In other words, if you decide to place a poster at xi, then you cannot place a poster on any other bulletin board that is within D feet of xi. Given ((x1,v1), . . . ,(xn,vn),D),  describe  a  linear-time  algorithm  which  computes  a legal  postering  campaign  which  achieves  the  maximum  total  viewership.   Analyze  therunning time of your algorithm

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Any thoughts on this problem ? Please share your efforts.

Comment: _First_ describe a linear-time algorithm, and _then_ analyze its running time? Oh, and is it assumed that none of the $v_i$ people who see a poster at position $i$ are also among the $v_j$ people who set it at position $j$?